# Mysql - Selecionar os registros com maior quantidade de inserções num determinado periodo

Tags: mysql, sql

estou precisando selecionar todos registros mais recorrentes (top 5) dentro de um intervalo de tempo mas não estou conseguindo.

Basicamente quando faço isso:

```
SELECT assunto, count(*) AS total 
 FROM tabMsgs 
WHERE dtCriacao > '2021-05-08' AND dtCriacao < '2021-05-16' GROUP BY assunto 
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Obtenho a contagem de registros, agrupados por assunto em ordem decrescente limitado a 5... Ótimo, mas agora que sei quem são os top 5 assuntos com mais contagem de registros e suas respectivas quantidade eu quero selecionar todos esse registros.

Estou fazendo assim sem sucesso:

```
SELECT id, assunto, dtCriacao 
  FROM tabMsgs A 
 WHERE dtCriacao > '2021-05-08' 
   AND dtCriacao < '2021-05-16' 
   AND assunto = (SELECT max(assunto) from tabMsgs B WHERE B.assunto = A.assunto);
```

Essa consulta está retornando todos os registros neste intervalo de tempo, mas preciso que retorne todos os registros dos 5 assuntos com maior quantidade de registros.

Não sei se fui claro.

Comment: coloque exemplo de dados na pergunta. Sobre as queries, na segunda pode usar `BETWEEN` na data, e na subquery filtre os 5 assuntos que quer e use `AND assunto in (` que talvez seja suficiente, mas sem ver os dados fica dificil dizer mais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `INNER JOIN` com essa `sub-query`, algo assim:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.assunto, a.dtCriacao
FROM
    tabMsgs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        assunto, count(*) AS total
    FROM
        tabMsgs
    WHERE
        dtCriacao > '2021-05-08' AND
        dtCriacao < '2021-05-16'
    GROUP BY
        assunto
    ORDER BY
        total DESC
    LIMIT
        5
) b ON
    a.`assunto` = b.`assunto`
WHERE
    a.dtCriacao > '2021-05-08' AND
    a.dtCriacao < '2021-05-16'
```

Comment: pode usar o `BETWEEN` para filtrar as datas mas, é preciso filtrar duas vezes, já q a subquery já faz isso?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, é necessário duas vezes por que vai ser buscado todos os registro que possuem o assunto igual aos localizados na subquery, então retornaria de todas as datas.
Não coloquei o BTWEEN para mostrar que o que ele já estava fazendo não estava tão longe de encontrar a solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, a resposta do @RobertodeCampos rodou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.